# Laravel : Sum with related models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm a trying to get the total distance of an activity which has multiple steps (with distance) ? For now, I'm doing like this :

Controller :

```
$total_distance = 0;
foreach (\Auth::user()->activities as $key => $activity) {
    $total_distance += $activity->getTotalDistance();
}
```

Activity Model :

```
public function steps()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Step');
}

public function getTotalDistance()
{
    return $this->steps->sum('distance');
}
```

Is there a proper solution to do that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me, if it's something you are going to reuse throughout the app you may be better off moving the code from the controller into a scope in your model.

Comment: If this solution is too slow for you (many activities with many steps), you will be better with querying your database for that. Probably one, not excessively complex query will do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you do it requires quite a lot of DB queries to be run:

- 1 to fetch user activities
- 1 per activity to fetch its steps

You can get the number you need with just one query using Eloquent's aggregate function **sum()**:

```
$total_distance = Step::join('activities', 'activity_id', '=', 'activities.id')->where('activities.user_id', Auth::id())->sum('distance');
```

You can read about other aggregate methods that Eloquent offers here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#aggregates

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Jeemusu said, your approach seems fine. But if you want to do it in some other way you can try to do it in several ways.

Look at [Laravel's Has Many Through relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships).

> The "has many through" relation provides a convenient short-cut for accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. For example, a Country model might have many Post through a User model.

So using has many through you can access steps directly something like

```
$user->steps->sum('distance');
```

You need to make relationship that user has many steps through activities.

Something like:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function steps() {
        $this->hasManyThrough('Steps','Activity','user_id','activity_id');
    }
}
```

The other solution is to put foreign key in steps table so you can directly access it from user model like:

```
$user->steps->sum('distance');

class User extends Eloquent {
    public function steps() {
        $this->HasMany('Steps','user_id');
    }
}
```

Hope this can help you.